# CSS Media Queries not working on Wordpress Site

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make my coded buttons for pdfs/mp3s/mp4s not stack on each other in a asymmetrical way when the browser is faced with a different screen size. For example, when the screen size changes from large desktops approximately 1200px wide to tablet res of 1024px to 768px (landscape/portrait), the buttons stack on each other in a way that looks inefficient/unintended. See for yourself:
http://www.mannachurch.org/portfolio-type/insights-from-the-bottom-bunk/

Try moving the browser to something that would fit a 13 inch or a tablet and you get what I mean. This is just for the buttons, everything else looks fine.

I'm trying to resolve this issue using this media query code on that wordpress site in my header.php file:

```
 /* iPhones ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
    a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    } 
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        }
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        } 

}

@media all and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 400px) {

    a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        }
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        } 
}


  /* iPad in landscape----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        }
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        } 
    }

   /* iPad in portrait----------- */
   @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width :     1024px) and (orientation : portrait){
    a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        }
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        } 
}



 /*Larger screens -----------*/
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width: 1224px)  {
    a .btn .pull-left {
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        }
    a .btn .pull-right{
    margin: auto 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
        } 
}
```

It will not make those buttons do anything different!!

What am I doing wrong? Wordpress is frustrating enough because it's layered with an endless piles of CSS files. But I'm strugging to see why I can't grab these and make them work with media queries. I'm pretty sure my declarations are correct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Omit spaces in your CSS declarations like this `a.btn.pull-left`.

Answer (score 0):

All wordpress themes come with their own style.css file. Instead of putting css in a php file (header.php), you should edit the .css file. Your button overrides should work there.

Most themes also have their own custom css field in theme options as well if you do not feel comfortable editing style.css in the editor. It's the same thing though.